# How to add new items to an existing group in a JSON file and save back to memory?

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a JSON file which is like:

```
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "UniqueId": "Footballer",
            "Region": "Europe",
            "Country": "England",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Rooney",
                    "JerseyNumber": "10",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Aguero",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Nani",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add a fourth member to this group in app run time. The member details will be obtained from the XAML interface typed by the user. Now I need to know how can I add a member to existing group. Add after adding I need to save it in memory so that when next time the app is loaded it will show four members. I want to add fourth member details as:

> "UniqueId": "CITY", "Name": "Yaya", "JerseyNumber": "5", "Position":
>   "Midfielder"

and the final json file should look like this:

```
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "UniqueId": "Footballer",
            "Region": "Europe",
            "Country": "England",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Rooney",
                    "JerseyNumber": "10",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Aguero",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Nani",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Yaya",
                    "JerseyNumber": "5",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I've been able to read content from the Json file using:

```
private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
{
    if (this._groups.Count != 0)
        return;

    Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/Data2.json");
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
    string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
        DataGroup group = new DataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                        groupObject["Region"].GetString(),
                                        groupObject["Country"].GetString());

        foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Members"].GetArray())
        {
            JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
            group.Items.Add(new DataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                         itemObject["Name"].GetString(),
                                         itemObject["JerseyNumber"].GetString(),
                                         itemObject["Position"].GetString()));
        }

        this.Groups.Add(group);
    }
}
```

Please help me to add new member and save that JSON back to memory.  In short, how do I append new data to the JSON and overwrite old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new JSON object doing this:

```
JsonObject newGroupObject = new JsonObject();
newGroupObject.Add("UniqueId", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("UniqueId"));
newGroupObject.Add("Name", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("Yaya"));
newGroupObject.Add("JerseyNumber", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("5"));
newGroupObject.Add("Position", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("Midfielder"));

// Output:
// {"UniqueId":"UniqueId","Name":"Yaya","JerseyNumber":"5","Position":"Midfielder"}
Debug.WriteLine(newGroupObject.Stringify());
```

Then, add the new JSON object to a JSON array:

```
// TODO: Replace following line with code that loads and parses the
// JSON string from a file.
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse("{\"Groups\": [{\"Members\": []}]}");

JsonArray groupsArray = jsonObject.GetNamedArray("Groups");
JsonObject firstObject = groupsArray.GetObjectAt(0);
JsonArray membersArray = firstObject.GetNamedArray("Members");

membersArray.Add(newGroupObject);
```

Finally, stringify the root JSON object and persist to a file:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
    "Data2.json",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(
    file,
    jsonObject.Stringify());
```

Find more [Windows.Data.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx) samples here.

Comment: This method is useful to add new objects to existing "group". but I need to add members to an existing object. Here we are adding under "Groups", I want to add my data under "Members". This is inside a group object I think. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sample updated. Consider reading the Windows.Data.Json examples from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx

Comment: How can I delete this added item if I want to?

Comment: With `membersArray.RemoveAt(3)`, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.jsonarray.removeat

Comment: How do I get the `Index` of a Member if I know the `UniqueId` of that member? Is there a search method to find out the Index?

Answer (score 0):

You read your file to *stringjsonText * so if you got a raw text there. 
How about use this code

```
stringjsonText.Replace("]}]}", +"," + rowOftextyouwant + "]}]}");
```

You look for the last few characters that are "]}]}", I assume they don't repeat anywhere in the file, and replace them with your prepared text. Because there is comma before every "row" you add this and end with the same characters you replaced so everything you need to do now is save this to the file.

To save:

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, stringjsonText);
```

I don't have much time right now and it's the fastest solution I could have think of.

Comment: Let me see if it works for me. I will let you know after that. thanks.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I did replace the last part of text with the json format and tried to save but nothing happened. No error, no save. Is there is any way to add item like " JsonArray jsonArray.Add() " method?

Answer (score 0):

If you save it to installation folder ms-appx:/// I dont think you can write it because its isolated and read only.
Try to put it in LocalFolder. You can read your json from installation folder and copy it to local folder.